# Procmail sends an extra email

Tags: forwarding, procmail

I use procmail to forward certain 'From' to a Gmail account

/home/user/.procmailrc

```
:0c
* !^FROM_MAILER
* ^From: .*aaa | bbb | ccc.*
! ^X-Loop: user@gmail\.com
| formail -k -X "From:" -X "Subject:" \
-I "To: user@gmail.com" \
-I "X-Loop: user@gmail.com"
:0
* ^From: .*aaa | bbb | ccc.*
$DEFAULT
```

This works fine but on my server inbox I also get an 'undelivered' mail

> The mail system   <"^X-Loop:"@my-name-server.com> (expanded from
>   <"^X-Loop:">): unknown user:
>       "^x-loop:"

**How can I avoid this?**

I've tried to delete these mails. 
This is not the best way.

Anyway It does not work.

```
:0B * <"\^X-Loop:"@my-name-server.com> 
/dev/null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recipe contains multiple syntax errors, but the bounce message comes because you lack an asterisk on one of the condition lines, which makes it an action line instead.

The general syntax of a Procmail recipe is

```
:0flags       # "prelude", with optional flags
* condition   # optional, can have zero conditions
* condition   # ...
action
```

The `action` can be a mailbox name, or `!` followed by a destination mailbox to forward the message to, or `|` followed by a shell pipeline.

So your first recipe is "If not from mailer and matching From: ..., forward to `^X-Loop:`.

The `| formail ...` line after that is then simply a syntax error and ignored, because it needs to come after a prelude line `:0` and (optionally) some condition lines.

Additionally, the `^From:` regex is clearly wrong.  It will match `From: .*aaa` or `bbb` (with spaces on both sides, in any header, not just the `From:` header) or `ccc`.

Finally, the intent is apparently to actually forward the resulting message somewhere.

```
:0c
* ! ^FROM_MAILER
*   ^From:(.*\<)?(aaa|bbb|ccc)
* ! ^X-Loop: user@gmail\.com
| formail -I "X-Loop: user@gmail.com" | $SENDMAIL $SENDMAILFLAGS user@gmail.com
```

If you simply want to forward the incoming message, the other `-X` and `-I` and certainly `-k` options are superfluous or wrong.  If they do accomplish something which is irrelevant for this question, maybe you need to add some or all of them back (and also remember to extract with `-X` any new headers you add with `-I`, as otherwise they will be suppressed; this sucks).

Your second recipe is also superfluous, unless you have more Procmail recipes later in the file which should specifically be bypassed for these messages.  (If so, you will need to fix the `From:` regex there as well.)

Comment: .*(aaa|bbb|ccc).* This means 'contains one of them' ?... You suggest (.*\<)?(aaa|bbb|ccc) This means 'start with <aaa OR <bbb...? (without ending the line with .*)

Comment: The regex `(.*\<)?` means "anything, as long as it ends on a word boundary" (`\<` succeeds at a word boundary, in Procmail's regex dialect, and many others). So yes, this basically translates to "From: header contains one of aaa or bbb or ccc, not embedded in a longer string" (depending on the probability of false matches, you may also want to add a `\>` guard after the last closing parenthesis).

Comment: You don't need a trailing `.*` -- a regex succeeds if the expression can be matched anywhere in the string.